# Reference value from state’s input, using JSONPath syntax in combination with a hard-coded string

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

Im creating a SSM document with a state machine, in the api parameter: Name.

I want to combine a value from the state’s input (`InstanceID`) with the hard-coded text `EC2-PROD-WEBSRV-CP_RAM_SWAP-Document`.

Im wondering if something like `"key2.$": "$.inputValue[+hardcodedstring]"`  is possible.

So the final value will be `i-013165f64447e25e0-EC2-PROD-WEBSRV-CP_RAM_SWAP-Document`.

SSM [CreateDocument](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDocument.html#systemsmanager-CreateDocument-request-Name) schema:

```json
{
   "Attachments": [ 
      { 
         "Key": "string",
         "Name": "string",
         "Values": [ "string" ]
      }
   ],
   "Content": "string",
   "DisplayName": "string",
   "DocumentFormat": "string",
   "DocumentType": "string",
   "Name": "string",
   "Requires": [ 
      { 
         "Name": "string",
         "Version": "string"
      }
   ],
   "Tags": [ 
      { 
         "Key": "string",
         "Value": "string"
      }
   ],
   "TargetType": "string",
   "VersionName": "string"
}
```

I read the documentation but It seems it is possible just one or the other option.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-jsonpath-effectively-in-aws-step-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `States.Format` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-generic) to interpolate the value into a string:

```json
"key2.$": "States.Format('{}-EC2-PROD-WEBSRV-CP_RAM_SWAP-Document', $.inputValue)"
```